# Conditional SQL Query on Multiple Rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to find out which customers have defaulted on their loans. I would like to query the dataset to find the *User_id* of customers who have not paid in the last 60 days, but and not sure how to implement this in SQL.

```
User_id    Due_Date                Loan_Amount    Paid_Amount
1          2012-04-04 16:14:12    500            40
1          2012-05-04 16:14:12    500            40
1          2012-06-04 16:14:12    500            0
1          2012-07-04 16:14:12    500            0
1          2012-08-04 16:14:12    500            0
2          2012-02-15 03:30:55    2030           100
2          2012-03-15 03:30:55    2030           100
2          2012-04-15 03:30:55    2030           100
3          2012-01-03 12:24:42    777            10
3          2012-02-03 12:24:42    777            0
3          2012-03-03 12:24:42    777            0
3          2012-04-03 12:24:42    777            0
```

In pseudocode (shown in bold) would look something like this, but I can't seem to implement it in MySQL:

SELECT User_id from TABLE_NAME WHERE Loan_Amount > 0 AND [**the value Paid_Amount has been null for over 60 days**]

Desired Output:
Users 1 and 3 in the above query would be returned because they have not paid for three consecutive periods.

NOTE: Due_Date is a time stamp

Any ideas would be very much appreciated!

Comment: I removed the extraneous database tags.  Please feel free to add the tag(s) for the database(s) you are really using.

Comment: Can you show which records from your data you expect the query to pick up?

Comment: Would it be possible to use a timestamp as the Due_Date instead of the date string?

Comment: Do you have a loan detail table? How do you know when a payment is due?

Comment: @Peter M I have updated the post with further details. And the Due_Date values is a timestamp

Comment: @mrtig The date of each payment instalment is shown in the Due_Date column. That is when the next payment is due.

Comment: Suppose that only last Loan_Amount should be checked `Loan_Amount > 0`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you can use the `DATEDIFF(date1, date1)` function to obtain a list of delinquent borrowers.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
     user_id
FROM table_name n
     JOIN (SELECT user_id, max(due_date) maxDate FROM table_name GROUP BY user_id) t 
          ON n.user_id = t.user_id 
         AND n.due_date = t.maxDate
WHERE 
     loan_amount > 0
     AND paid_amount IS NULL
     AMD DATEDIFF(due_date, getdate()) > 60
```

Answer (score 0):

My previous query was wrong, try this

```
select distinct t1.User_id
from TABLE_NAME t1
    inner join (
        select ts1.User_id, sum(ts1.Paid_Amount) as Paid_Amount_Total
        from TABLE_NAME ts1
        group by ts1.User_id
    ) t2
        on t1.User_id=t2.User_id and t1.Loan_Amount>t2.Paid_Amount_Total
)
where
    t1.Loan_Amount > 0
    and t1.User_id not in (
        select ts2.User_id
        from TABLE_NAME ts2
        where ts2.Due_Date>=DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 60 DAY) and ts2.Paid_Amount>0
    )
```

t1, ts1, ts2 - are aliases for TABLE_NAME

Comment: Thanks for this but what does t1 and t2 refer to here?